# demo code that will read printer job status via serial port

Tags: printer-control-language

Is there a demo code somewhere - libraries etc that will help me read printer job status given the job is printing wholeday. Need a report of how many jobs got printed or thier status via an api or some framework preferably web services

Regards

Comment: You probably will want to state which printer you are using, because a solution for one printer won't be a solution for another. If you're using HP, you can start with the [HP/PCL Reference Manual](http://www.hp.com/ctg/Manual/bpl13210.pdf).

Comment: It’s Printronix and they do have pgl that are native libraries not sure reusable across serial port ?

Comment: No idea, sorry.